# How to make downloadable File-type field in transformation -Kentico

Tags: kentico, custom-type

Resently started to  work with kentico 6.0 .
I have build custom document type with field of "File" type, where administartor can upload file.
Now i'm trying to build a transformation from where site users will be able to download this file:
(like zipped source code of projects in codeproject) 
Is where a easy way to do it in kentico?
thanks

Comment: I have the same problem.
here is my solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65328962/14832657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to look into the built-in Transformation methods available to you (found at /CMSHelp/index.html?newedit_transformation_methods.htm of your Kentico instance).

In this case, I think what you want is `GetFileUrl(object attachmentGuidColumn)`

You'd do something like `<a href='<%#GetFileUrl("NameOfTheDataField")#>'>File</a>`